# chaining lodash methods that contain _.reduce

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I'm trying to take an array and run it through a short chain of Lodash methods. I first reduce the array to a string, and then I'm wanting to trim out certain characters from this string.

```
const reduceAndTrim = data => 
  _.chain(data)
    .reduce((acc, fav, idx) => `${acc}${data.type}:${data.ID}`, '')
    .trim('-'))
    .value();
```

I'm getting a value of `false` at the end of this, and I'm not quite sure why.

If I try to just use `_.reduce` and remove `chain`, `trim`, and `value`, `reduce` works as expected.

My understanding is that `reduce` will take as its first argument `data`, and then `trim` will take the return value of the `reduce` method as its first value.

I'm also not sure if `reduce` can be chained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `_.reduce()`, and `_.trim()` are not chainable by default (see list under [The wrapper methods that are not chainable by default are](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#lodash)). In addition, chaining requires the (almost) the entire lodash bundle, and tree shaking won't work as well.

A more functional approach, that accepts any function, and works with tree shaking is `_.flow()` (or `_.flowRigh()`):

```js
const reduceAndTrim = _.flow(
  data => _.reduce(data, (acc, fav, idx) => `${acc}${fav.type}:${fav.ID}`, ''),
  str => _.trim(str, '-')
);

console.log(reduceAndTrim([{
  type: '---type',
  ID: 'ID----'
}]))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

And it's even more powerful when using [lodash/fp](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide), since lodash/fp functions are auto curried, and the parameters are iteratee-first data-last, and have fixed arity (number of parameters). This means that you can supplying the iteratee function to `_.reduce()` would return a new function that waits for the data, and you can easily compose it using flow (you don't need to create an arrow function, and pass `data` explicitly).

Note: I've replaced `_trim()` with `_.trimChars()`, since trim in lodash/fp doesn't accept an optional character due to fixed arity 1.

```js
const reduceAndTrim = _.flow(
  _.reduce((acc, fav, idx) => `${acc}${fav.type}:${fav.ID}`, ''),
  _.trimChars('-')
);

console.log(reduceAndTrim([{
  type: '---type',
  ID: 'ID----'
}]))
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

Comment: Wow -- thank you. This is amazing. I was also looking for that page with the unchainable methods.